# Rails scafolding associations has_many error: 1 error prohibited this product from being saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want the all products should be added depending on the brand,
I have a brand and product scaffolding,
I generate brand like this: rails generate scaffold Brand brand:string 
and generate product has_many assosiation with brand scaffolding:
rails generate scaffold Product productname:string brand:references

my brand model

```
class Brand < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :products
end
```

product model

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :brand
end
```

brand migration

```
class CreateBrands < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :brands do |t|
      t.string :brandname

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

product migration

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.string :productname
      t.references :brand

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Brand controller

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.string :productname
      t.references :brand

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Product controller

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @products = Product.all
  end

  def new
    @product = Product.new
  end

  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @product }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end

  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.update(product_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @product }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @product.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to products_url, notice: 'Product was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private.
    def set_product
      @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    end

    def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:productname, :brand_id)
    end
end
```

I succesfully crud operation with brand but I tried new product depending on brand I get an error:
1 error prohibited this product from being saved:
Brand must exist

How can I fix this, thanks for suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

before create product you should have brand record,
when create product, you should include which brand that will be connected to that product
and that information saved through brand_id (see: t.references :brand)

in your ProductsController.rb add @brands

```
  class ProductsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    def new
      @product     = Product.new
      @brand_list  = Brand.all.map { |c| [ "#{c.brandname} ", c.id] }
    end

  end
```

in your view file that create product add field to choose brand below is sample

```
  <%= f.select :brand_id, @brand_list, { include_blank: false } %>
```

Comment: Thanks for feedbakck, yes first created brand record tried your solutions but get an error ProductsController  like this syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting '}' end

Comment: sorry I missed } for line @brand_list  = Brand.map { |c| [ "#{c.brandname} ", c.id]  }, I just added

Comment: Again get an error: undefined method `map' for #<Class:0x0000000010abcd58> Did you mean? tap